# What is the frequency of separable prefix verbs (vs. inseparable) in German?

Tags: verb, separable-verb

I am just a beginning student of German and recently read about separable and inseparable verb prefixes.  It made me curious about the frequency of each in the German language.  Does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: Could you provide examples?

Comment: What do you mean saying "frequency"?

Comment: @Alex.S: Relative frequency, probably, but a clarification would be good.

Comment: @chirlu There’s relative frequency in a dictionary (1 instance each) or a text corpus (0 to *n* instances) and if the latter, do only separated occurences count? So yes, the question is probably underdefined, but still answerable, if one wanted to cover all variants or dared to make an informed choice.

Comment: @Alex.S: »Frequency« ist der englische sprachwissenschaftliche Ausdruck für »Häufigkeit«. Lisa will wissen, wie viele trennbare Verben es im Vergleich zu untrennbaren gibt. Das aber vermutlich nicht auf Basis einer Abzählung in einem Wörterbuch, wo jedes Wort genau einmal vorkommt, sondern auf Basis einer Auszählung einer sehr großen Textmenge, die den tatsächlichen Gebrauch möglichst getreu wiedergibt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the database of [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/) we get a [list of all separable verbs listed](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?service=inflectionRules&filter=VerbSeparable&inflectionClass=Trennbare%20Verben&entryClass=Cat%20V). In the introductory page we read:

> **9176** Einträge der Flexionsklasse **Trennbare Verben**
>   von insgesamt **18202** Verben im Canoo Wörterbuch.

Hence, in this (incomplete) database there are roughly 50% of verbs listed as separable.

Comment: This answers my question and thank you for doing so.  My personal program of language study shuffles through a selected set of languages and I was winding down my study of German when I asked this question, so consequently, I didn't happen to notice that this question had received some replies until just now.  Please forgive the delayed award of the green checkmark.

Comment: @Lisa: at least you did come back - great :)

Answer (score 2):

I assume frequency refers to how often separable prefixes are used on a regular day, so the answer is: a whole lot. You will definitely need to understand the various meanings of separable and inseparable verb prefixes in order to have command of the language.

It's hard to say exactly the most used separable and inseparable prefixes, but I found a few interesting pages that can help you understand the meaning of the most commonly used verb prefixes.

Resources: 
http://www.nthuleen.com/teach/grammar/sepinsepprefixexpl.html
http://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/Wortbildung/Separables.html

#### Bonus Mini Lesson

The concept of prefix separation is not too complicated once you differentiate the separable and inseparable prefixes. For example,

Verb: **abschließen (to lock)** 
Separable Prefix: ab- 
Verb Root: schließen (to close, to shut)

> Er schließt die Tür ab. (He is locking the door.)
>   
>  **or** 
>   Er muss die Tür abschließen. (He has to lock the door.)
>   
>  **or** 
>   Er hat die Tür abgeschlossen. (He closed the door.)

In the second sentence, the verb and prefix are not separated because there is another verb which precedes it (müssen). In the third sentence, however, a -ge- is added in between the separable prefix and the verb root. This is common with many separable verbs when used in the past tense.

Verb: **besuchen (to visit)** 
Inseparable Prefix: be- 
Verb Root: suchen (to search, to seek)

> Er besucht seine Mutter. (He is visiting his mother.)
>   
>  **or** 
>   Er muss seine Mutter besuchen. (He has to visit his mother.)
>   
>  **or** 
>   Er hat seine Mutter besucht. (He visited his mother.)

In all cases and tenses, the inseparable prefix is attached to the verb root.

Comment: Welcome. I think the frequency the original post refers to is relative (as in the title, the separable vs. unseparable prefixes).

Comment: Thank you. Okay, I see. Well, when comparing separable and inseparable verbs to each other, there is no definitive answer as to which is used more.

Comment: That's right, with so few criteria one cannot tell. No definitive answer till the OP edits the question.

Comment: This is mainly a comment and an answer to a question not being asked.